# log4j appender only sending my messages to stdout, but not remote GELF appender

Tags: java, logback, log4j2, graylog2

I'm having a strange issue where log4j is correctly displaying all my log messages the console, but is only sending log messages to my graylog server that I am not writing (e.g. a library I'm  using which writes to `log.info` will show up in graylog, but not any of the messages I write with `log.info`). What am I missing

Here's my `logback-spring.xml`

```
<configuration>
    <contextName>test</contextName>
    <jmxConfigurator/>

    <springProfile name="dev, test">
        <appender name="gelf" class="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.GelfLogbackAppender">
            <host>udp:localhost</host>
            <port>5555</port>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <extractStackTrace>true</extractStackTrace>
            <filterStackTrace>true</filterStackTrace>
            <mdcProfiling>true</mdcProfiling>
            <timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS</timestampPattern>
            <maximumMessageSize>8192</maximumMessageSize>

            <includeFullMdc>true</includeFullMdc>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>INFO</level>
            </filter>
        </appender>
    </springProfile>

    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.test" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="gelf" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I'm instantiating my log by doing:

```
 private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

And writing to my log:

```
 logger.info("WHY CAN'T I SEE THIS IN MY GRAYLOG SERVER");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Your are specifying that the loggers of the package `com.test` should only write to the `stdout` appender.

```
<logger name="com.test" level="info" additivity="false">
   <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</logger>
```

You should change it to:

```
<logger name="com.test" level="info" />
```

---

Make sure that you are running your app with the matching profile for your gelf appender.

Comment: If I wasn't using the correct profile, then nothing would appear in my graylog server though. As it stands, the only messages appearing in my graylog server aren't sent from my application code, but from libraries/dependencies